# Database : Design table with dynamic tags

Tags: database

In my table, there is a list of items, those items have some attribute that is dynamic. it means it can change through run-time, not design-time.

For example, a list of dishes. So, a dish can be a fish/dessert/drink/.... Those attributes will help my application filter it later base on user. And those attribute is inputted by manager through run-time.

So, I don't know how to design a table with dynamic attribute like this. Who has any ideas, please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: why can't you store dish names as data? plz be more specific. what is the deign you currently have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a type column to your table.

Another approach would be to have something like a tag. Where you item has many tags.

However, more details on what you're trying to accomplish would be necessary in order to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to database design? you should probably look at some db design tutorials:

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html 
http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_getting_started_with_db_design/index.htm

The attributes that you mentioned could be stored as data in some database table under column dishes. 
And then you could relate these dishes with your users.